# How to set awesome-wm windows colors

Tags: awesome-wm

I just installed and started getting used to Awesome WM and I find it great!
I'm currently stuck triying to change the colors of the client windows, and would like some help.

The original environment is Manjaro Xfce with Vertex-Maia-Dark theme and I would like to have a similar look under Awesome.

I've played around with the awesome themes configuration, with theme.lua file, and checked here and on the old wiki but cannot find a solution/guide/answer. I'm not looking to change just fonts and title bar colors, but what is contained on the client windows -the inside borders and menus of the opened apps-.

Where should I look for that?

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is exclusively limited to questions about software development. Consider [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for questions about configuring your desktop environment. (Config files that are scripts are obviously a corner case -- something that's clearly a scripting question as such is welcome here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awesome does not handle setting the Qt/GTK theme as it is outside of the scope of a window manager. Please take a look at the following references to learn more on the subject of manually setting the theme.

[How to make awesome wm look awesome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179461/how-to-make-awesome-wm-look-awesome)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK+#Themes

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Appearance

Note that the Arch Linux theme documentation applies to every distributions and will always be more up to date than this stack overflow post and is the reason why it isn't in Awesome FAQ